# Usage of don as verb

Tags: word-usage

The attire don them as soldiers.
 Is it grammatically agreeable to make a sentence using the verb form of 'don'as mentioned above?

Comment: No. Look up *don* in a dictionary.

Comment: Their attire make us believe that they are soldiers.In a similar way don as being used in the meaning "put on " be used to make a meaningful sentence. Well, I am a non-native speaker of English.So some of the postings may appear rather odd for native speakers of English language.However,StackExchange is a forum to express our views and to get response from native speakers of English language.

Comment: Yes, but *don* specifically means "put on, like a piece of clothing".  It doesn't mean "makes appear".

Comment: And a person *dons* a piece of clothing, not the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

If the dictionaries' definitions aren't enough for you to understand how to use the word, look at the examples they give.  Cambridge only gives one example, but Oxford gives more than twenty (I've quoted the first three).

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/don):

> **don** verb [ T ] *formal* to put on a piece of clothing:
>
> *He donned his finest coat and hat.*

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/don):

> **don**: Put on (an item of clothing)
>
> *‘in the dressing room the players donned their football shirts’*
>
> *‘He even donned his special summer shirt and shorts in celebration as the sun came out.’*
>
> *‘I don't mind donning my sou'westers for my daily medicine walk but cycling in the rain doesn't appeal at all.’*

As StoneyB observed: "A person dons a piece of clothing, not the other way round."

Your sentence is incorrect:

> <s>The attire don them as soldiers</s>

The following would be correct:

> The attire is donned by the soldiers
>
> The soldiers don the attire
>
> The soldiers don their attire
>
> The soldiers are donning their attire
>
> The soldiers have donned their attire

Answer (score 0):

Yes  it's "grammatically agreeable" with *dons*.

We also have *Clothes make the man* when we know that people make clothes. So it's a different meaning of *make*. Likewise  it is permissible in English to do similar with other verbs. Thus *The attire dons them as soldiers* is permissible with the understanding that *don* is being used in a creative way.

Comment: "the attire dons them as soldiers" does not sound right in any dialect of English I'm familiar with.  Can you find an example of it being used that way?